# out of memory errors since moving the PC on to a domain

Tags: windows-7

The following applications

- Outlook 2010
- Visual Studio 2008 sp1
- Firefox 6.0

are all causing out of memory errors since moving the PC on to a domain, I used USMT 3.0 to migrate the user profiles, I have checked the resource manager and the memory usage is high, but it has happening in different apps on different users, the PCs were fine for the last year, before the move on to a domain. Any assistance at this stage would be good.

The environment is:

- Windows 7 Professional OS
- 2 GB RAM
- Intel DUO core processor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DELL thanks, BCMWLTRY.exe has a memory leak on it, I moved program up into the parent directory. It did not reboot up on the next restart. All has worked well since doing that. Memory leakage has essentially ceased. It would appear the BCMWLTRY.exe has no purpose or use.

To make sure I have also disabled the service.